# Make element height full page

Tags: html, css, sass, material-ui, material-design

I am using some material-ui for my page design. I have several grid elements and they load as per random picks of menu:
[image]

Yellow colored grid is the menu. 1,2 and 3 are options for it. Every option is different page (url) but menu is the same in all of them and it is imported in them. Every different page has different height - for example selected option in example (1) is  with very small height. But option 2 has is very long and height becomes over 100vh. I added for my menu (yellow colored) a height of 100vh but it is becoming too short when I choose option 2:
[image]

as you can see the red lines indicates the end of the Menu. How can I make this menu to fill page to the bottom as `height: "100vh"` is working only for smaller pages.

Comment: without HTML its hard to tell, you can use `height: 100%` in your sidebar but I am not sure if that's gonna work. because `height: 100%` makes the sidebar height the same height of its parent.

Comment: yes, height:100% makes sidebar as height as parent div. Maybe I should stick to this anyway

Answer (score 1):

height: 100%

or use flexbox, so you'll have

```
<div class="whole-page">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.whole-page {
  display: flex;
}
```

https://codepen.io/agakesik/pen/NWxYQJY

and it will automatically use full height

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  height: 100% to your yellow area css..

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  --
  --
}
```

Comment: it depends on the parent element.

Comment: Yes, @Pain is right. height of 100% is not doing the trick, I tried it already :)